# Django Migrations not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, migrate

I don't know what's going on. Migrations always worked fine for me, but seems to me that now something is wrong.

It's the second time that my python manage.py migrate does not work when I have just installed a third party app and want to migrate.

This time it is happening with my django-crispy-forms. I did pip installed it and put it settings.py INSTALLED_APPS list.

Did anybody ever dealt with something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That's all I get, no error at all, but the migration is not coming through all the way. At least my forms are not getting crispy (but oddly enough is seems that it is).

`(Pax) ~/desktop/Pax/src   $ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(Pax) ~/desktop/Pax/src   $ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/tree/dev/crispy_forms) doesn't contain any model or migration file, so it shouldn't do anything for migrate

Comment: That makes sense, I thought that all my third party apps would need to migrate, but this one doesn't really interacts with the database.